# Calculus: Method of Increments

Tags: calculus

I'm going through the exercises in an older Calculus book.

Using the method of increments, find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ where:

Given that **$\Delta y$/$\Delta x$ = [sin(Xo+$\Delta x$) - sinXo)]/$\Delta x$**, use the identity: **$\sin A- \sin B = 2\cos(\frac{A+B}{2}) \sin(\frac{A-B}{2})$**

I was able to do this for:

**$\sin(A+B) = \sin A \cos B + \cos A \sin B$**

, in which I substituted $X_0$ for $A$ and $\Delta x$ for $B$.  The result for that one was $\cos(X_0)$ .

[sin(Xo)cos($\Delta x$) + cos(Xo)sin($\Delta x$) - sin(Xo)]/$\Delta x$

sin(Xo)[cos($\Delta x$)/$\Delta x$] + cos(Xo)[sin($\Delta x$)/$\Delta x$]
sin(Xo) * 0 + cos(Xo) * 1 = cos(Xo)

But I can't seem to solve this one.

I found this identity:
$\sin A - \sin B = 2 \cos [ \frac{A + B}{2} ] \sin [ \frac{A - B}{2} ]$

And unfortunately for this one, no answer is provided in the book.

Comment: To find $\frac{dy}{dx}$, we need to know what $y$ is - you haven't mentioned this

Comment: You are probably expected to assume that $\cos(\Delta x) \to 1$ and $\sin(\Delta x) \to \Delta x\,$. See [A trig question: Who first knew that sin' = cos?](http://www.ms.uky.edu/~carl/ma330/sin/sin1.html) for some background and history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by you found the identity, when the problem statement specifically says to use it.

But the calculation is straightforward:

$$\begin{align}\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} &= \frac{\sin(x_0 + \Delta x) - \sin(x_0)}{\Delta x} \\ &= \frac{2\cos\left(\frac{(x_0 + \Delta x) + x_0}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{(x_0 + \Delta x) - x_0}{2}\right)}{\Delta x}\\ &= \cos\left(x_0 + \frac{\Delta x}2\right)\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\Delta x}2\right)}{\frac{\Delta x}2}\\ &\to \cos(x_0)\cdot 1\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks, that is the right answer.  I was able to get a download of the solutions manual.

Comment: I tried to vote for your answer but I don't have enough points, sorry.

Comment: While I am curious why you wouldn't be able to accept it as the answer (you shouldn't need reputation for that), it is quite all right. Being useful is what I am trying for, not points. (Since I have enough rep to do everything I am interested in doing at this point.)